# Can a directory accessed by web named "system" cause vulnerability issues on a web server?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, filesystems

This is probably a very silly question, but I would like to make sure...
Can a directory under public_html (running linux / apache) named system cause any vulnerability issues?

Thank you

EDIT: or conflicts with actual system directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server is secured, file name at that level should not be a security risk. I am not aware of any conflict by filename at public_html directory.

Comment: Hi, what do you consider "secured" ?

Comment: I'm not a guru on this topic, but u may want to check out some security best practices on this topic. They basically protect against   most vulnerabilities. http://www.boran.com/security/webserver_practices.html http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,11525,00.asp. You may also want to keep your eyes on advisories such as this one from Rapid7 http://www.rapid7.com/security-center/advisories/R7-0033.jsp